# Serializing object to uri without escaped character

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to **serialize** object to uri where space character are not encoded in javascript.

so if I have object

```
foo={
  name:'omkar asish',
  type:'person'
};
```

serialize -> foo

Observed result : `name=omkar%20Aasish&type=person`
expected result: `name=omkar asish&type=person`

I have used `toQueryString()` which internally uses encodedURIComponent therefore I am still getting escape character as encoded.

Also I have used query-string module which still gives the same result.

**UPDATE**
foo object sometimes contains keys with `underscore`
Ex: foo={
name:"omkar",
type:"person"
}

OR

foo={
_name:"omkar",
_id=1
}

I just want to **filter** out this underscore from your expression which is coming irrespective of the key

Comment: you can use `decodeURIComponent` on the result

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fails to exhibit any prior effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @YanFoto So you are not able to resolve? I clearly mention to clip or trim underscore if present

Comment: I could resolve it, but the task is trivial and stackoverflow is not really your private tutor.

Comment: I am not asking you to be private tutor....the thing is I've not used reduce before and I needed the solution faster though I could have gone with the tutorials but not enough time to go though it....if you have a solution please provide else doesn't matter....it's a small update will take a time to do it later.

Answer (score 0):

I know there must be a better way, but just because I love [`reduce`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/reduce) so much:

```js
let foo = {
  name:'omkar asish',
  type:'person'
}

const keys = Object.keys(foo)
let res = keys.reduce((acc, cur,i) => `${acc}${cur}=${foo[cur]}${++i < keys.length ? '&' : ''}`, '')

console.log(res)
```

Or if you rather want to have a function for that:

```js
function serialize(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return keys.reduce((acc, cur,i) => `${acc}${cur}=${obj[cur]}${++i < keys.length ? '&' : ''}`, '')
}

console.log(serialize({hello: 'world', it: 'works'}))
```

Comment: but I don't know the keys its varying sometimes I get name and type or sometimes I get name and id....though I don't know in future If I have more different attributes

Comment: @OmkarAsishParida it does not matter, this solution will work anyway (as long as you don't have nested objects). Just give it a try!

Comment: Perfectly working but I am getting '_' before each key since default it has _name,_id...   how do i remove it?

Comment: in name and type i m getting _(underscore) can I get generic code to reduce this too

Comment: @OmkarAsishParida I don't understand. Please add this special case to the question.

Comment: I have updated underscore problem in my question above.